Assembly - Why does my code not print the result I have gotten from the math function to console from the main function?
.data

A:  .word 5
B:  .word 3
C:  .word 2
D:  .word 4

.text
.globl main

main: 
lui  t0, %hi(A) 
addi t0, t0, %lo(A) 
lw  t1, 0(t0) 
add  a0, t1, zero 
jal ra, push

lui  t0, %hi(B)
addi t0, t0, %lo(B)
lw  t1, 0(t0)
add  a0, t1, zero
jal ra, push

lui  t0, %hi(C)
addi t0, t0, %lo(C)
lw  t1, 0(t0)
add  a0, t1, zero
jal ra, push

lui  t0, %hi(D)
addi t0, t0, %lo(D)
lw  t1, 0(t0)
add  a0, t1, zero
jal ra, push

jal ra, math

jal ra, pop

addi a7, zero, 1
ecall

addi a7, zero, 10
ecall

push: 
addi sp, sp, -4
sw   a0, 0(sp)
jalr x0, ra, 0

pop: lw   a0, 0(sp)
addi sp, sp, 4
jalr x0, ra, 0

math:

jal ra, pop             
add  s0, a0, zero
jal ra, pop             
add  s1, a0, zero
jal ra, pop
add  s2, a0, zero
jal ra, pop
add  s3, a0, zero

add s4, s3, s2      

sub s4, s4, s1     

addi s4, s4, -10   

add s4, s4, s0      

add a0, s4, zero           
jal ra, push


I have tried to create a separate function to print the result to console, but it only works if the lines of code are at the bottom of my code. For example if I put it below the math function. Is it possible to somehow write the code so it initiates the print from the main function? (This is the only problem I have with this code as it works as stated in the example. Would be nice to know if there is a possible way to change so the result of the code is printed from the main function.)

Your math function doesn't return.  After jal ra, push, it falls off the end into whatever bytes are next and tries to decode them as machine code.  Probably 00000000 which faults.  Or print: if you put it there. Use the debugger to single-step and see what happens.

Also, using functions to push and pop really overcomplicates your code.  And makes your functions non-leaf, so they need to save/restore ra if they want to return to their own callers.  Reserve stack space once, and use sw/lw with offsets from SP to store into it.  Also, the standard calling convention passes the first few args in registers, the a registers are named for the argument-holding purpose.

x86 version of the same problem: What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs
